# How to fix "Cannot implicitly convert type object to System.Attribute"?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm a newbie on programming and I had a working code, and I updated my .NET package on nuget (I'm using UWP), and after that, this part of the code stopped working.

```
[...]
 if (eh != null)
            {
                Delegate d = (Delegate)(object)eh;


/// This one >
 IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes = d.GetMethodInfo().DeclaringType.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false);

///
                int count = 0;
                using (IEnumerator<Attribute> enumerator = attributes.GetEnumerator())
[...]
```

I got this error:

> CS0266    Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: wow, for such a small amount of code, its nearly unreadable, please think about formatting your code before you press submit

Comment: Just cast the object to IEnumerable like this : `Enumerable<Attribute> attributes = (IEnumerable)(d.GetMethodInfo().DeclaringType.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you are trying to push an object array `object[]` into an `IEnumerable<Attribute>`, it's not going to happen.

Simply use [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://Enumerable.Cast(IEnumerable)%20Method)

> Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type.

```
 var attributes = d...
                   .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)
                   .Cast<Attribute>()
```

Comment: Weird enough, this code worked before... But thanks!